# How many setIntervals is too many in good practice?

Tags: javascript

I like to spice my sites up with effects (not too many) but i generally have 3-4 intervals going. Just wondering if anyone knows if i'm stretching barriers or can i have a lot more if i wanted?

Comment: Define `effects`. If it's the same `effects` 90s websites are known for, 1 is too many.

Comment: Well, that depends. Do they trigger every 5 minutes or every 50 milliseconds?

Comment: lol jquery animation spurts and position increments

Comment: generally very quick intervals

Comment: I'm looking for a general ballpark here. my site runs smooth and fine.

Comment: There is no, and should be no, rule of thumb for this. It's entirely dependent on the situation. Sorry, but this is not a real question (see the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)).

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest any setinterval is too many, you should always use settimeout instead. The reason for this is that javascript is single threaded. This means that if some code (maybe the function in setinterval) blocks the timeout call, setinterval will continue to issue more calls to the function. With small intervals this can result in function calls stacking up causing EXTREMELY hard to find/reproduce bugs.

Best practice here is to just use settimeout within the function itself. So if you previously had:

```
function foobar()
{
// do some stuff 
}
setInterval(foobar, 100)
```

You should change it to:

```
function foobar()
{
//do some stuff
setTimeOut(foobar, 100)
}
```

This has the added benefit that you can add a bit of logic in to check if you actually want to run the function again.

Answer (score 2):

If you are afraid of having multiple timers, use 1 timer and make the effects fire every nth time the timer counts down. It depends on what you are trying to do though.

Comment: Hey i like that idea. Thats gotta be better.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on how long each one takes to execute, and the delay between each.

Your browser will queue these calls up, so if you're worried about slowing down the user's browsing experience (or jerky animations), you can probably detect with some fairly simple timing code whether you are missing the desired interval. You could then reduce (or increase) the number of effects being shown as appropriate.