# Executing code inside setInterval function only once per few seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, setinterval

I'm working on a simple project that is HTML and Javascript; and I have a problem with my timer.

I'm calculating the seconds between two `Date()` objects; and every 2 seconds, I want to get a new random number. I have a `setInterval` that runs every 100 ms and when I get past the 2 second mark, the code inside the `if` statement should run.

So my question is:
How can I make sure the code execute only once per 2 seconds in an `if` statement that is inside a `setInterval()` that runs every 100 ms?

Here is the code:

```
var startTime = new Date();
var endTime = new Date();

var randomNumber = 0;

var gameTimer = setInterval(function(){
    //calculate seconds;
    var secondsPassed = Math.round( (endTime - startTime) / 1000 );

    if(modulo(secondsPassed,2) == 0){
        //when the "gate" is open this keep executing every 100 mili seconds.
       //but i want it to execute only once every 2 seconds.
        randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*lanes.length);
        $(lanes[randomNumber]).append(box);
    }

    endTime = new Date();
}, 100);

var modulo = function (n, m) {
    var remain = n % m;
    return Math.floor(remain >= 0 ? remain : remain + m);
};
```

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking here...

Comment: Why not just give setInterval a duration of 2000 rather than 100?

Comment: becuse i want to add more things to it that run faster then 2000 mili and endTime will not be refreshed fast enough.

Comment: So use clearInterval(gameTimer) when your conditions are met in your setInterval.

Comment: why don't you have two setintervals, one ever 100 mili and the other every 2000?

Comment: There is nothing in your code that would cause the if statement to execute twice. It is possible, somewhere else in your code, you are starting the gameTime twice.

Comment: @Markasoftware didnt think about it, its that a good practice?.

Comment: @mattsnider i think its execute more then once, becuse the timer is on 100 mili and it keep runing when the if statment is set to true.

Comment: I don't know about good practice (I don't see anything wrong with it) but it works smoothly on my website. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7693898/how-many-setintervals-is-too-many-in-good-practice

Comment: i added the modulo function in the end of the code :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are asking for a double-interval timer.

```js
var interval = 100, beat = 2000, ticks = 0;
var timer = setInterval(function(){
    runsEvery100ms(); // ««« Code here runs every 100 ms.
    if (ticks > 0 && ticks % beat === 0) {
        runsEvery2000ms(); // ««« Code here runs every 2000 ms.
        ticks = 0;
    }
    ticks += interval;
}, interval);
```

[**Demo Fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/onury/aQvVv/)

Comment: thank you, becuse of my bad english it was very hard to expline what i wanted to do. but you understand it! again thank very much :)